# my dynamic table row insert

Tags: php, jquery

I created a dynamic table row provide as in http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/OeZkZ#comments

i am facing problem in inserting into database using loop.

the first row is taking fields as the its 0 var

{
                        
                        1
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }

```html
$count = 1;
if(isset($_POST['byMonth']))
{
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
 
  $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
    $month = $_POST['month'.$i];
     $actual = $_POST['amount'.$i];
      
   //$date = $_POST['entry'.$i];
  echo $que = "insert INTO worker_by_month(uid,year,month,actual_amount,date) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$year."','".$month."','".$actual."','".$entry."')";
 $mysqli->query($que);
  $count = $_POST['items'];

}
 

}

this is what i have done.
```

Comment: Can you show what have you done?

Comment: you have to only capture inputs there. Arrange input box'es name as an array for eg  name="row[0][1]"

Comment: $count = 1;
if(isset($_POST['byMonth']))
{
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
 
  $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
    $month = $_POST['month'.$i];
     $actual = $_POST['amount'.$i];
      
   //$date = $_POST['entry'.$i];
  echo $que = "insert INTO worker_by_month(uid,year,month,actual_amount,date) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$year."','".$month."','".$actual."','".$entry."')";
 $mysqli->query($que);
  $count = $_POST['items'];

}
 

}

this is what i have done.

Comment: the first query is not taking values; the rest are well inserted.